# Create XML document in PHP

Tags: php, xml, arrays

I want to create a XML document from these arrays I have. The arrays looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Firstname1
    [1] => Firstname2
    [2] => Firstname3
)

Array
(
    [0] => Lastname1
    [1] => Lastname2
    [2] => Lastname3
)
...........
```

I want the XML document to be structured like this:

```
<Member>
<Firstname>Firstname1</Firstname>
<Lastname>Lastname1 </Lastname>
</Member>
```

How can I do that? Thanks for help!

Comment: Have you tried anything? We're not here to do your work.

Comment: pretty much a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397036/how-to-convert-array-to-simplexml

Comment: Use [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)

Comment: Have you tried the [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) in PHP?

Comment: [xml from array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397036/how-to-convert-array-to-simplexml).

Comment: A bit of googling would have helped you enormously ... There are tons of [tutorials](https://www.google.nl/search?q=php+create+XML&aq=f&oq=php+create+XML&aqs=chrome.0.57j60j0l3j62.2683&sugexp=chrome,mod=0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this: http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

And code (just for example how to build such structure):

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<xml></xml>');
foreach($first as $k=>$v){
    $member = $xml->addChild('Member');
    $member->addChild('Firstname',$v);
    $member->addChild('Lastname',$last[$k]);
}
```